Latest way on updating an ESLint config file (2024)
Trying to create a new React project with vite. I usually setup ESLint via the npx eslint --init and then get an .eslintrc.cjs file which I afterwards modify for my preferred formatters. Once done, I get a config similar to the following:
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      env: {
        node: true,
      },
      files: ['.eslintrc.{js,cjs}'],
      parserOptions: {
        sourceType: 'script',
      },
    },
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'react', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0,
  },
};


However, after updating my npm version and running the ESLint config command, I now seem to get an eslint.config.js instead with the following contents:
import globals from 'globals';
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';
import pluginReact from 'eslint-plugin-react';

export default [
  { files: ['**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,jsx,tsx}'] },
  { files: ['**/*.js'], languageOptions: { sourceType: 'commonjs' } },
  { languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser } },
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  pluginReact.configs.flat.recommended,
];


The format for this config is very different than the one I got used to. How do I modify this updated ESLint config file such that I could configure it to follow rules for formatters from other packages?
P.S.: I just discovered that I could still get an .eslintrc.cjs if I just run npm init @eslint/config instead, but would also still want to know how to format the updated ESLint config file.

That's the new flat config format with the 9.x branch of eslint. If you want to do it the other older way you can pin to 8.x or I believe there's also an adaptor function for the older config style. See the documentation for more details.

This question is similar to: How do I configure ESLint flat config with Typescript in VSCode? (without FlatCompat). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

ESLint recently changed the default config format. The legacy .eslintrc file format is no longer enabled by default. Instead, the new ("flat") config format uses a file like eslint.config.js. You can read more about this on:

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files: the new config files documentation
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide: is a migration guide

For typescript-eslint specifically, the docs on https://typescript-eslint.io show both the flat and legacy configs. You can read about those on:

https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started: for the base 'getting started' guide
https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/typed-linting: for adding in typed linting
https://typescript-eslint.io/packages/typescript-eslint#config: for the optional tseslint.config helper function to get type information and a bit nicer extends support

